# Pop Up Message On Excel Cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

I would like to have a pop-up message to remind the user to proceed to section iii to complete the rest of the input.

I attempt to use Data Validation>Input Message but the message is always there. I would like the message to turn up only when the user selects `YES` at Cell J26.

Any formula I can use or VBA to show the reminder message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In K26:

=IF(J26="YES","message_text","")

Text should spill over into adjacent cells as long as they are empty, but you could merge K26:N26 to ensure the text is displayed.